# Does datacontract serialization use reflection?

Tags: serialization, datacontractserializer, datacontract

XmlSerialization creates a serializer proxy for each class. The proxy resides in a different assembly so it can serialize only public fields.

DataContract serialization can serialize private fields too. Does it mean it uses reflection? Isn't it slower than using a proxy (except for the first time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This protobuf-net page](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/Performance) shows the performance of `DataContractSerializer` to be significantly better than `XmlSerializer`. Of course, you should always test with your own data, but if you are looking to replace `XmlSerializer`, you will most likely find `DataContractSerializer` to be a performance improvement.

I'm not sure how `DataContractSerializer` is implemented internally, but generally serializers are highly optimized. This is especially true for `DataContractSerializer` since it is a big part of the performance picture for WCF. It is not uncommon for a serializer to generate MSIL code on the fly. When this is done, `DynamicMethod` allows you to (surprisingly!) bypass visibility checks (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod.aspx)), so it is possible to access private fields without reflection.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfk2s47t.aspx):

> Given sufficient security permissions,
>   a serialization engine implemented
>   using dynamic methods can access
>   private and protected data to enable
>   serialization of objects not authored
>   by the engine creator.